# regex: alphanumeric spaces and dash on keyup

Tags: javascript, regex

I've seen plenty of posts close to what I'm looking for, but I'm still getting errors and was hoping for some regex help. I have a form field that needs to allow alphanumeric, spaces, and dashes. Ideally the spaces and dashes would not be consecutive.

I want this to fire on keyup so that the user doesn't have the option to type these forbidden characters.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm throwing bad escaping errors and this code does not work in firefox. Thanks for your help!

```
$('#your_name').keypress(function (e) {
    var allowedChars = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (allowedChars.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}).keyup(function() {
    var forbiddenChars = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\ ]", 'g');
    if (forbiddenChars.test($(this).val())) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(forbiddenChars, ''));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#your_name').keyup(function (e) {
    var allowedChars = /^[a-z\d -]+$/i;
    var str = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode || e.which);

    var forbiddenChars = /[^a-z\d -]/gi;
    if (forbiddenChars.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(forbiddenChars, '');
    }

    if (allowedChars.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```